# Correct lazy loading syntax in angular and ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Can you explain to me this syntax in detail?

```
{ path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)}
```

Thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules
Detail explanation

Comment: ^ This comment. Can't emphasize it enough : **use the documentation !**

Comment: ^^ yeah, well finding the documentation is the problem, everyone uses the documentation if they can find it in the myriad of changes

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that if the particular route `home` is called, then the component inside `HomePageModule` will be lazy loaded for that request.

Comment: what do we insert in the import and then statement?